# Excel and Sumproduct

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm stuck. I'm trying to capture some data.
Namely, type of incidents in a postal code, in a spreadsheet organized by month (Apr 2015-Mar 2016).

Here's what I have so far:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Apr 2015'!E10:E114="Complaint")*('Apr 2015'!I10:I114="L7J"))
```

BUT, that only captures data from one of the sheets. I need it from `Apr 2015-Mar 2016`. How do I do this? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Look up `3D COUNTIF` you will find your answer.

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you're looking for...

Have an intermediate sheet, where you do each month on its own. Assuming you can only get one type of incident per, you can run a second sumproduct on that, to get your final results.

A bit clunky, but it gets the job done.